# Eureka form, TextAreaRow auto height

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

Can I configure a TextAreaRow of an Eureka form to fill the available vertical space?
I will have just a few rows above and toolbar at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to play with `textAreaHeight` property values by setting up it initial height depending on device and available bottom space. Check out this pull request https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/pull/416/files to see how it works.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use textAreaHeight attribute to change the height dynamically

using **.dynamic(with initial height value).**

```
<<< TextAreaRow(){
        $0.tag = tag
        $0.placeholder = "PlaceHolder"
        $0.textAreaHeight = .dynamic(initialTextViewHeight: 96)
    }
```